# Destroy Range Slider after Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
$("#ask-for-offer").on('click', function () {
    $(".form-oferta").toggle();

    setTimeout(function() {
        // range slider here
        var slider = new Slider("#ex19");
        slider.on("slide", function (sliderValue) {
            document.getElementById("ex6SliderVal").textContent = sliderValue;
        });

        //slider.destroy();
    }, 300);
});
```

But I dont know how to use slider.destroy after toggle.

I want to initiate the slider when I toggle, then when I press again the toggler to destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `toggle()` is the right method for toggling the creation and destruction of an element. I would probably do something like the following instead:

```js
const container = $('#container');
$('button').click(() => {
  let slider = $('#slider');
  if (slider[0]) {
    slider.remove();
  } else {
    container.append('<div id="slider"></div>');
    slider = $('#slider');
    slider.slider();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle Slider Create / Destroy</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```